# String buffer help needed

Tags: java, string, netbeans, stringbuffer

I did exactly what has been instructed in this tutorial(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hyVmCqiCNmY) of stringbuffer, but I am getting an error in Netbeans with an orange line right across this line of code

`StringBuffer b = New StingBuffer("how are you doing today");`

whereas when Iam doing the same thing in eclipse, there is no such error

Program:

```
public class StringBuff {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuffer b = New StingBuffer("how are you doing today");

        System.out.println(b);
    }

}
```

I tried to add the image of the program from Netbeans, but I don't qualify yet to add images.

Comment: Plase report the error message.

Comment: New StingBuffer? new StringBuffer

Comment: should be  StringBuffer b = new StingBuffer("how are you doing today");

Comment: Side comment: StringBuffer is obsolete and has been for some time - I would try to find a more up to date tutorial if I were you...

Comment: Thank you! Now my question is resolved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have typo in `New`. Java is case sensitive so `New` is different than `new`.

BTW [`StringBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) is supplemented by [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). The orange line does not indicate an error but code that should be improved.

> This class is designed for use as a drop-in replacement for StringBuffer in places where the string buffer was being used by a single thread (as is generally the case). Where possible, it is recommended that this class be used in preference to StringBuffer as it will be faster under most implementations.

[Read the official Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), not some YT video.

Comment: Thanks, its resolved, but i learn better with a human teaching method than reading.

Comment: I must be getting old because while I agree with text from this answer I don't see how it answers the question. StringBuffer is OK, but StringBuilder is better when we don't need synchronization. IMO this answer will be valid only if added info that Java is case-sensitive and `New` is not the same as `new` (unless problem in question was not described properly and NetBeans really warns us about StringBuffer in single-thread application).

Comment: Pshemo, this answer did not resolve my question, but since my question was resolved, I had to close the question, right(according to SO gidelines)?. We have to tick the tick mark right. The other members who answered me, did not have the tick mark ,next to their Names, So i can tick it, and this website does not have separate resolve button.So I had to choose something.

Comment: @Jboy "We have to tick the tick mark right" no, accepting answers is not mandatory, but it is right decision to accept *correct* answer. By *correct* I mean answer which actually explains problem from your question and provides solution to it. This answer is useful, so it deserves few up-votes, but it doesn't explain problem from your question, so IMO it shouldn't be accepted. If you want to *close your case* by accepting some answer but there is no correct one, post your own answer and accept it, or ask answerer to include solution of your main problem, so you could accepted his answer.

Comment: @Jboy I edited this answer to include solution of your main problem so now it is OK to accept it.